# How to fix Fivestar/Voting API to make the appearance option selectable?

Tags: views, rating

I am using Drupal 7.19, and the following modules:

- Views 7.x-3.5
- Voting API 7.x-2.10
- Fivestar 7.x-2.0-alpha2

With older versions of the above modules there is the option of the following field configure setting: "Appearance: Fivestar Stars (display only)." The result is a view displaying Fivestar stars.
The mentioned versions do not give that field configure setting option. The result is a view displaying a number.

[The problem was bugging others too](http://drupal.org/node/811882). Some solutions are suggested on that page, but none makes sense to me.

I'd like to know how to solve this.